# wrap text on cell with BIRT report exported to PDF

Tags: eclipse, reporting, birt

I have the next problem, i need wrap this text on this cell, but appear cropped

example:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sah6.png)

but full text is: 0123456789ABCDEFGH
and only showed: 0123456789ABCD

how can wrap the text on the cell?, im using BIRT Report 4.6 on Eclipse Neon

Answer (score 2):

Based on : 
http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/19827-how-do-i-use-word-wrap-in-report-design/?s=173b4ad992e47395e2c8b9070c2d3cce

If you're using a resource, add this function inside. If not, you can just copy and use the code inside the function.

The variable longStr is your long string you want to wrap so (0123456789ABCDEFGH)
and width is the size you want to authorize for your string so it's 15 for you.

```
/** 
* Format a long String to be smaller and be entirely showed
*
*@param longStr 
*             the String to split
*@param width
*               the character number that the string should be 
*
*@returns the string splited
*/
function wrap(longStr,width){ 
    length = longStr.length; 
    if(length <= width) 
        return longStr; 
    return (longStr.substring(0, width) + "\n" + wrap(longStr.substring(width, length), width)); 
 }
```